# How to get record based on the Two Column Group WONO, AssortSLNo & Based on the Total need SecID

Tags: sql

How to get Unique SecID row based on the WO, AssortSLNo, TL Column
Table

```
SecID    WONo   AssortSLNo     TL   
11       46       1            35976    
12       46       1            34593    
9        46       3            14639    
23       46       1            12761    
87       46       3            34738    
74       46       2            30575    
2        46       1            29952    
67       46       2             8993
```

Result

```
SecID   WONo    AssortSLNo       TL 
11      46         1           35976    Higest Value
74      46         2           30575    
87      46         3           34738
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Or are you just hoping someone will do it all for you?

Comment: And are you using SQL Server? Or SQLite? Please remove the incorrect tag.

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags... feel free to add back the single, correct tag.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you mean that for each (distinct) AssortSLNo value, you want the row having the highest TL value?

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correctly you need `AssortSLNo` wise unique row with the highest `TL` value. You can use `row_number()` window function with common table expression to achieve this easily.

Query:

```
with cte as
  (
   select SecID,WONo,AssortSLNo,TL,row_number()over (partition by assortslno order by tl desc)rn 
   from YourTableName
  )
select SecID,WONo,AssortSLNo,TL from cte where rn=1
```

Output:

| SecID | WONo | AssortSLNo | TL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 46 | 1 | 35976 |
| 74 | 46 | 2 | 30575 |
| 87 | 46 | 3 | 34738 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/M4sQXamq)

`row_number()` window function is not available in sqlite. You can achieve same result with sub-query and aggregation like below:

Query:

```
SELECT 
    SecID, WONo, AssortSLNo, TL 
FROM  (
    SELECT SecID, WONo, AssortSLNo, TL,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTableName t2 WHERE t2.AssortSLNo = t1.AssortSLNo AND t2.TL >= t1.TL) AS rn
    FROM YourTableName t1
) cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Output:

| SecID | WONo | AssortSLNo | TL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 46 | 1 | 35976 |
| 87 | 46 | 3 | 34738 |
| 74 | 46 | 2 | 30575 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9rVHCe04)